# How to get anchor tag text when the text is assigned through AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a web page that has a list of news items with a `'Leave a comment'` link for each news item. The website is developed using `Sitefinity CMS`. What I need to do is change the `'Leave a comment'` link text to `'Comments(0)'`

Here is the screenshot of the scenario:
[image: Here]

In Sitefinity I could not find a straightforward setting to change that text for the link. So, I tried to modify the text using jQuery.

Here is the **HTML** code I see when I **INSPECT** in Google Chrome `'Leave a comment'` link.

```
<a href="#commentsWidget" id="ctl00_camaincontentPlaceholder_C001_masterBlogPostsFrontend_ctl00_ctl00_Repeater_ctrl0_commentlink" 
class=" sfcommentsCounterWrp sfcommentsShort" threadkey="f61abde8-0049-628e-b41a-ff0100332b8d_en" 
displaymode="ShortText">Leave a comment</a>
```

When I do the following using `jQuery`, I just get empty string as output

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.sfcommentsCounterWrp.sfcommentsShort').each(function () {
        alert(" the anchor text is : " + $(this).text());

    });
});
```

Upon some research and debugging I realized that though inspect element HTML code above shows me the text for the link in its HTML, the source code does not have any text within the anchor tag.

The HTML for anchor tag on view source page is :

```
<a href="#commentsWidget" id="ctl00_camaincontentPlaceholder_C001_masterBlogPostsFrontend_ctl00_ctl00_Repeater_ctrl0_commentlink" class=" sfcommentsCounterWrp sfcommentsShort" threadKey="f61abde8-0049-628e-b41a-ff0100332b8d_en" displayMode="ShortText" href="SfCtrlPresentation/#commentsWidget"><span></span></a>
```

The text for the anchor tag is being inserted using AJAX request from a built in control within sitefinity, which I have no control over.

My jQuery is checking for text on `document.ready`, at which point only DOM is ready and not all external resource contents, which is why it returns an empty string.

This is where the Leave a Comment text is added to the page from:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Comments.Web.UI.Frontend.CommentsCountControlBinder,
 {"commentText":"Comment","commentsText":"Comments","leaveCommentText":"Leave a comment","ninetyNinePlusText":"99+","serviceUrl":"/RestApi/comments-api"}, null, null);
});
```

I also tried to call my jQuery function from within a `Sys.Application.add_load(myfunction);` since it occurs after `Sys.Application.add_init()` but still the anchor text is empty.

Additional Information:

1. I tried executing my JS code in `window.onload()`, `jQuery(document).on("load")`, returns empty string
2. I have my JS code in a separate file, and I currently have it at the end of the page just before the closing `body` tag.
3. I tried by adding my JS code elsewhere, like the `head` tag, but still did not help.
4. anyone interested in taking a look at the web page directly [click here](http://cms.staging.alfa.chrysleracademy.com).

I would like to know if you have any suggestions on what `JQuery` or `javascript` event I need to call my code in, so that it executes after the text has been placed in the anchor tag? Or a complete page load. Or do you know of any other workarounds for this?

**EDIT:**
When I try to execute the `.text()` code from jQuery directly in the console on the browser it picks up the text

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/169338)

Comment: Try putting it into the callback function you've posted above `Sys.Application.add_init()`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `add_init` is just a queue of functions to call on initialization.
This is untested, but something along these lines may work for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
        $('.sfcommentsCounterWrp.sfcommentsShort').each(function () {
            alert(" the anchor text is : " + $(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```